# Keyboard keys not working properly via KVM/QEMU

Tags: 16.04, server, keyboard, kvm-virtualization, qemu

My hosting provider enables me to access my VPS via their website using KVM/QEMU. I have yet to figure out how this is possible, as I've not installed anything at my end for this to work. I find this confusing to say the least.

Here's what it looks like:

[image: KVM/QEMU]

When I use the keyboard, some keys are messed up. For instance, Shift + 3, should be "/", but ends up being "É".

I've made sure the keyboard was setup correctly (PC105, ca) by confirming /etc/default/keyboard.

No problem with SSH.

How do I make this QEMU work similarly to SSH? Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Comment: You have to set the keyboard map n the guest OS as well. You might not be able to use the console until after you have done so (e.g. via ssh).

Comment: To make sure I'm explaining myself properly... My hosting provider has a protected client area on their website that contains a component (QEMU?) enabling me to connect to my VPS (Ubuntu 16.04). I'm using Firefox on Windows 10. Noting SSH from home is ok, not so much from work, which is why I'm investigating this. Using the web based component brings up this weird keyboard mapping issue. The keyboard on Windows 10 works as intended, unsure if you meant this as the guest OS?

Comment: The guest OS is the virtual machine provided by the VPS provider. The one whose console is in that window.

Comment: I used `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` to confirm the appropriate keyboard on the server (via SSH). Rebooted afterwards as well.